# jQuery dataTable sorting customisation

Tags: jquery, datatables

in .cshtml file

```
<div class="@tableClass"> 
    <table id="@tableId" class="inner-block-table low-blood-table home-ver" data-url="data2.json" data-pagination="true" data-search="true">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- sortable -->
            <th data-field="diaryEntry" class="diaryEntry" data-sortable="true" data-sorter="diaryEntry">@diaryEntryHeader @if (isViewAllTable)
                                                                                                                           { <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>}</th>
            <th data-field="recordedSymptoms" class="recordedSymptoms" data-sortable="true" data-sorter="recordedSymptoms">@recordedSymptomsHeader  @if (isViewAllTable)
                                                                                                                                                   { <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>}</th>
            <th data-field="whileSleeping" class="whileSleeping">@whileSleepingHeader</th>
            <th data-field="activity" class="activity">@activityHeader</th>
            <th data-field="impact" class="impact">@impactHeader</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
          @foreach (DiaryEntry item in Model.DiaryEntries)
          {
              //Mytask page--Show last one Entry in SP, View all should show all entries
        <tr class="@if (i++ == 0 || isViewAllTable)
                   { @firstRowClass }">
                <td class="diaryEntry">
                <div class="heading-label sm-heading-label-visible">@diaryEntryHeader</div>
                <div class="heading-desc">@item.EntryDate.ToShortDateString()</div>
            </td>
            <td class="recordedSymptoms">
                <div class="body-label">@recordedSymptomsHeader:</div>
                <div class="body-desc status">
                    @{ if (item.DateOfSymptom != "Not Applicable")
                       {

                            @item.DateOfSymptom
                      <span>@item.TimeOfSymptom</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span>Not Applicable</span> 
                       }
                    }
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="whileSleeping">
                <div class="body-label">@whileSleepingHeader</div>
                <div class="body-desc">@item.SymptomWhileSleeping</div>
            </td>
            <td class="activity">
                <div class="body-label">@activityHeader:</div>
                <div class="body-desc">
                      @item.Activity
                </div>

            </td>
            <td class="impact">
                <div class="body-label">@impactHeader:</div>
                <div class="body-desc">
                    @item.Impact
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
          }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in my js file

```
 var filterByDate = false;
var table = $('#GridWithPaging').dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{"targets": [2,3,4], "orderable": false}],
    //responsive: true,
    //"aoColumns": [
    //            null,
    //            null,
    //            { "bSortable": false },
    //            { "bSortable": false },
    //            { "bSortable": false }
    //],
    "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sInfo": "Showing  _START_ - _END_ out of _TOTAL_ event logs from:",
        "sInfoFiltered": ""
    },

    //"scrollX": true,
    //"scrollY": false,
    //dom and table tools are required to show download buttons
    //"dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "sEmptyTable": "No diary entries!",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "dom": '<"top"<"col-xs-12 col-sm-8 show-results-area"i<"gridtoolbar">>>rt<"text-center"p><"clear">',
    //"sDom": '<"row view-filter"<"col-sm-12"<"pull-left"il><"clearfix">>>t<"row view-pager"<"col-sm-12"<"text-center"p>>>',
    tableTools: {
        "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                //"sTitle": "ExportToExcel",
                "sFileName": "TableTools - *.xlsx",
                "sButtonText": "ExportToExcel"
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                //"sTitle": "ExportToPDF"
                "sFileName": "TableTools - *.pdf",
                "sButtonText": "ExportToPDF"
            }
        ]
    }
    //"jQueryUI": true,
    //"scrollCollapse": true
});
```

Now while sorting other browsers giving expected result but in IE the data count becomes zero. The problem being the

```
<div class="heading-label sm-heading-label-visible">@diaryEntryHeader</div>
```

in first tbody>tr>td
The above div is causing problem in IE. This div is visible only in smartphones with media query css
Anyway of sorting jQuery dataTable so that it ignores first div in first column
I think we have to give some condition in the below area:

```
"columnDefs": [{"targets": [2,3,4], "orderable": false}],
```

OR

```
"aoColumns": [
  null,
  null,
  { "bSortable": false },
  { "bSortable": false },
  { "bSortable": false }
],
```

Any Suggestion is much appreciated

Comment: <tbody><tr><td><div class="heading-label ">some data</div><div class="heading-desc">somedata</div></td></tr></tbody>

Comment: This is not clear enough to answer. We need a full example of what data you're putting into the datatable, the markup before calling `.dataTable`, the expected result and what exactly goes wrong in IE. You say the data becomes null, but the code snippet you provide shows that the columns are null, which is a different thing. If possible, create a working example with the StackOverflow or 3rd party (jsfiddle, codepen etc.) snippet tool.

Comment: "columnDefs": [{"targets": [2,3,4], "orderable": false}], try this instead of  aoColumns

Comment: I tried it but it is still while sorting in IE it is still making data count 0.